# How to make jenkins run pod agent based on label

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I have Jenkins runs in k8s cluster, I have configured multiple pod templates so Jenkins uses them for building then deletes the pod agents, also added the build steps in a library using Jenkins-template-engine. I have created multiple pod templates (default, nodejs, name2, name3), "Then, based on the programming language the microservice has been written with, Jenkins is supposed to provision an agent from the pod template using label in jenkinsfile. For example, if a service is written in Python, it should use pod template name3 . Here is a snippet of the Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
        label: 'nodejs'
        if(case_1){

            // steps
            deploy_direct()

        } else if (case_2){

            //staging steps
            deploy_method_2()

        } else if (case_3){

            //case steps
            deploy()           

      }

}
```

I was expecting that based on label defined above, jenkins run pod agent from, but it mostly runs from default pod template.

[image]

it rarely uses the label to specify which pod template jenkins shall use to provision the pod agen like this:

[image]

what am I missing or doing wrong?